# if statement and user input advice

Tags: java

My user inputs work fine, my problem is I want an `if` statement that will say  `are both inputs equal?`, but I get the attached error.

I need the code to be: `if cork is entered in batman and robin?`. This is what I tried:

```
System.out.println("From " + batman);  
System.out.println("To " + Robin);

if(batman.equals("Cork") + Robin.equals("Cork") {

} else {
    System.err.println("");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Replace `+` with `&&`.

Comment: `&&` should be used to check condition for `AND` not `+`.

Answer (score 3):

that here:

```
if(batman.equals("Cork") + Robin.equals("Cork") {
```

makes no sense because you are doing something like concatenating true with true or similar...

you have to do instead:

```
if(batman.equals("Cork") && Robin.equals("Cork") {
```

Comment: Yes I'm new to java an just need advice and thank you.

Comment: It is ok, nice that you learn from that...but remember to use the boolean operators

Answer (score 2):

Your code should look like this :

```
        System.out.println("From " + batman);  
        System.out.println("To " + Robin);
        if(batman.equals("Cork") && Robin.equals("Cork")) {
               // Statements
        } else {
            System.err.println("");
        }
```

Comment: It was error there that you had not closed a ")" of if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use && when requiring more then one test in an if statement.
+ doesn't work in such cases it simply concatenates values. Hope it helps :)